# where does the remainder goes in div operation (X86 tasm assembler)

Tags: assembly, tasm

The output of the below assembly code is expected to be 6 but it is coming as 3. What's wrong?

```
data_seg    segment 
msg1 db "hi",10,13,"$"
msg3 db 26
num db 10
data_seg    ends
code_seg    segment
assume  cs:code_seg, ds:data_seg
start:
        mov ax,data_seg                 ;init
        mov ds,ax

    loop1:
        mov ah,0
        mov al,msg3
        div num
        mov ah,02
        int 21h
    term:   
        mov ah,4ch          ;termination code                       
        mov al,0
        int 21h
code_seg    ends
end start
```

Comment: Sigh... look up what `div` divides by what. In your case, the remainder is in `ah`... so you promptly clobber it. `mov dl, ah` may fix you up.

Comment: Oh yeah... if you expect to see a number, `add dl, '0'`...

Comment: the remainder is going to ah and not dl. Just checked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/div.html):

> Unsigned binary division of accumulator by source.  If the source
>   divisor is a byte value then AX is divided by src and the quotient is
>   placed in AL **and the remainder in AH**.  If source operand is a word
>   value, then DX:AX is divided by src and the quotient is stored in AX
>   and the remainder in DX.

Answer (score 1):

DOS function `AH=02h` expects character code in `DL` register.
Your division operation is `word(AX)/byte(10) -> quot(AL)+res(AH)` and doesn't change `DL`.